# Spring Validation Doesn't Work With Generic Types

Tags: spring-boot, spring-validator

In my code block, I just want to validate a controller method with Spring boot @Valid annotation for a generic Pair object. But the validation doesn't work for me.

My Controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void add(@RequestBody @Valid Pair<AddDto, AddUserDto> pair)
{
    ...
    service.add(pair);
}
```

Pair object looks like:

```
public class Pair<F, S>
{
    private F first;
    private S second;
}
```

AddDto object looks like:

```
public class AddDto
{
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    private List<String> actionList;

    ...getters, setters
}
```

AddUserDto object looks like:

```
public class AddUserDto
{
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    ...getters, setters
}
```

In this case, validation doesn't work for me. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with generics. The problem is that the Pair class does not define any validation rules. Try changing it to:

```java
public class Pair<F, S>
{
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private F first;
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private S second;
}
```